# Bad memory leak when creating a view - even though a 'release' is present?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

Part of my code presents a UITableViewController in the following way:

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
flipside = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];  
controller.delegate = self;
flipside.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:flipside animated:YES];
[flipside release];
[controller release];
```

Using the leaks tools, no memory leaks are picked up on. However, whenever I bring up the settings menu (as shown in the code above), more memory appears to be allocated and never released - almost 100 kB every time.

Weirdly, the inclusion of the two release statements at the end seems to have no effect on the memory allocation..? Is there something I am misunderstanding about memory allocation in objective-c, or is something weird going on?

Any ideas are much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: How are you measuring the memory increase? Also, are you measuring this increase in the simulator or on the device?

Comment: Using the simulator - run with the 'allocations' tool. The 'all allocations' item keeps rising significantly every time I open the settings menu.

Comment: Are you running with NSZombieEnabled set to YES?

Comment: I was using NSZombieEnabled to test it a while ago, but have since removed the option. I just tried running it on the actual device too - same result.

Comment: Looking through some of the alloc data, it looks like all of the objects present in the controller's Nib file are still loaded into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If flipside is a retained property then the navigation controller is leaking. the problem is that you are bypassing the accessor method and releasing flipside directly. This is just messy code. A better way to do it would be to make an accessor method for flipside that will only alloc a new one if you haven't already created one. It's called lazy loading. To do this, just leave the @synthesize for flipside (but you shouldn't set it from outside the accessor method), in your header file change the property to,  and add this method to the implementation:

```
- (UINavigationController *)flipside {
    if (flipside != nil) {
        return flipside;
    }
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [controller release];
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    // This implies a retain if your flipside property is set to retain
    self.flipside = navController;
    [navController release];
}
```

make sure to put `self.flipside = nil` in the viewDidUnload method of the view controller the code you included came from (I assume it's a presentSettings action).
what your presentSetting action should now look like is this:

```
- (IBAction)presentSettings {
    // make sure you use the accessor self.flipside instead on accessing the variable directly
    [self presentModalViewController:self.flipside animated:YES];
}
```